# Site urls not showing via domain name

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, migration

I just moved a wordpress site with a change of domain name. Instead of full migration, I imported posts and media using WP exporter. After importing the posts into the new wordpress installation, the homepage is accessible but posts are not found. These posts are available in the dashboard (admin area ) and accessible using the public ip, like 138.100.200.28/business-management/
However, if I try accessing them using the domain name like example.com/business-management/, I cannot access them. There are no entries in the .htaccess file yet except the default wordpress settings:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The site is hosted on apache server and using mariadb. Please help.

I have tried resetting permalink settings and deactivated all the plugins, but it did not fix the problem.